# Pyserial non-polling read

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

I am using Pyserial(a Python Serial lib) to read hex data from serial port on a raspberry pi, OS is raspbian.

I need to read from serial port one byte each time, and process the data immediately without any time delay. The way I am doing it now is just polling, constantly read from the port within in a loop. The problem is that it's taking almost 95% of CPU, and make other process slow.

I believe there is a better way to do this without using too much CPU resource. I used 'minicom' to monitor serial port, and it's not taking much CPU. So I wonder anyone who is familiar with Pyserial could help me, or anyone can tell me how minicom has done it.

Here is my code. Thanks a lot

```
while True:
    try:
        reading = ser.read().encode('hex')

        if reading == "":
            continue

        #always add to packet when it's not empty
        data_packet.append(reading)

        if check_byte == True:
            #sometimes, check byte could be 2a
            check_byte = False
            continue
        elif length_byte == True:
            #this byte is length
            packet_length = int(reading, 16)
            length_byte = False

        if packet_length == 0 and hex_equals(reading, "2a"):
            #start of a string
            #next byte is length
            length_byte = True
        elif packet_length > 0:
            packet_length -= 1
        elif hex_equals(reading, "23"):
            #end of packet
            data_packet_handle = data_packet
            data_packet = []
            handle_data(data_packet_handle)
        elif packet_length == 0:
            #if it's zero, the packet is over, but still have check and ending character
            #next byte is check byte
            check_byte = True
    except Exception, err:
        pass
        print Exception, err
```

Answer (score 3):

I have just solved my own problem.

Previously, I set 'timeout=0', so it's constantly checking the serial port.

Now I set 'timeout=None', it will wait until there is enough data coming from serial port. Now the CPU usage is only used when there is data from serial port, and it's not that much.

Here is the code to open a serial port:

```
ser = serial.Serial(port=serial_port, baudrate=2400, bytesize=8, parity='N', stopbits=1, timeout=None)  # open first serial port
```

Comment: There is no 'timeout=0' in your example code. Could you please post where to set this? Thanks.

Comment: ser = serial.Serial(port=serial_port, baudrate=2400, bytesize=8, parity='N', stopbits=1, timeout=None)